# dotnet publish with /p:PublishProfile=?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to call "dotnet publish" with a specific publish profile pubxml file as documented here :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

However, everything I try seems to result in the default behaviour, and the /p:PublishProfile part is ignored.

```
dotnet publish /p:PublishProfile="MyFolderProfile"
```

Doesn't work, and logs no error, building to the default location under "/obj".

I do note that an intentionally incorrect command has the same result though, eg:

```
dotnet publish /p:PublishProfile="MyFolderProfile-XXXXX"
```

What am I doing wrong? - Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Of course, it's not a solution, but I ended up listing all options (Release, output directory, etc.) manually

Comment: Have you tried specifying the project the profile was built upon? Like this:
`dotnet publish WebApplication.csproj /p:PublishProfile="MyFolderProfile"`

Comment: @VictorAlves I'm not the original poster, but I have tried with the project in the command line and that doesn't help either. It seems the problem is a long existing one, even using msbuild: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1901

It seems you will have to manually specify the parameters on the command line, e.g. `-c Release`,  `/p:PublishDir=dist`, etc

Comment: I only ever run into these issues with microsoft software.

Comment: See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62954314/73573

Answer (score 24):

My response is late. My solution has a simple .NET Core console application `ConsoleAppCore.csproj`. I used `Visual Studio IDE` to generate a publish profile with the name `FolderProfile.pubxml` and then the following commands worked for me:

**Relative path - From the solution root**

```
dotnet publish ConsoleAppCore\ConsoleAppCore.csproj /p:PublishProfile=ConsoleAppCore\Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile.pubxml
```

**Absolute path - From any location**

```
dotnet publish "C:\work\ConsoleAppCore\ConsoleAppCore.csproj"   "/p:PublishProfile=C:\work\ConsoleAppCore\Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile.pubxml"
```

**On Azure dev ops**

*Task name*=.NET Core

*Task version*=2

*Command*=publish

*Path to projects*=I left this empty

*Arguments*=

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\ConsoleAppCore\ConsoleAppCore.csproj /p:PublishProfile=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\ConsoleAppCore\Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile.pubxml  --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output  $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\ConsoleAppCore-Publish\
```

In the **Azure Dev Ops** build pipeline scenario, I have redirected the output to a folder under `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` . I also have a **Publish Artifact** task which is configured to use the staging directory variable.

I have made use of the publish profile XML file because I wanted a single file to govern the complete behavior while on **Azure Devops**. Relying on a single file for all parameters simplifies management on Azure.

**Azure Dev ops - Artifacts Explorer**

The `Publish Artifact` task created a drop for me and this is how it looks. Please notice that the file name in the explorer tallies with the name specified along with the `--output` option in the `dotnet publish` task
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work the same way on linux. The publish profile is simply ignored.

Comment: I can't speak for Linux but this is the most surefire way to get it to wok on Windows.

Comment: The "Relative path - From the solution root" solution worked for me! Thanks

Comment: Looks like full / relative paths should not be working now, as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish "If you specify a path and file extension when setting the `PublishProfile` property, they are ignored. MSBuild by default looks in the _Properties/PublishProfiles_ folder and assumes the _pubxml_ file extension. To specify the path and filename including extension, set the `PublishProfileFullPath` property instead of the `PublishProfile` property."

Answer (score 16):

I ran into the same issue a while ago. I managed to fix it by instead calling:

```
dotnet build [projectname] /p:PublishProfile=[PublishProfile]
```

Comment: What will `[projectname]` be?

Comment: Add `/p:DeployOnBuild=true` to deploy after build - see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-3.1#publish-profiles

Answer (score 10):

You might need the full path, e.g.

```
dotnet publish -c Release /p:PublishProfile=Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile.pubxml
```

Comment: Without specifying either sln or csproj file?

Comment: @AndersLindén yep I didn't need to specify that, but I probably just had a single .csproj file in the directory

Answer (score 10):

There is an open (as of Oct 2021) issue for Folder Publish with the similar symptoms https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/12490

Workaround I use for now is to manually edit `*.pubxml` file produced by VS.Net to have both `PublishUrl` and `PublishDir` keys with the same values.

With this `dotnet publish -p:PublishProfile=...` works as expected.

Comment: This was the fix for me. Thanks!

Comment: Note that as mentioned in the thread, this still ignores things like 'DeleteExistingFiles'

Answer (score 4):

Try this based on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-3.1#publish-profiles

```
dotnet build ..\project\project.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true -c Release /p:PublishProfile="Folder Staging"
```

I included a relative csproj path and a publish profile name with a space in it to clarify how to deal with those cases.  The `-c` flag is optionally used to specify the configuration to use.

Answer (score 3):

See https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/19677. The PublishProfile is only the name, any directory before it is disregarded.

> PublishProfile property is treated as a file name and the directory is
> constructed separately.

The `PublishProfileFullPath` property should be used if specifying a custom path.

Answer (score 3):

To solve the problem you must add a < PublishDir > property to your .pubxml file. Then the

```
dotnet publish /p:Configuration=Release /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile
```

command works fine.

Example below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121.
-->
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>false</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>false</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>true</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <PublishUrl>C:\MyApp\PUBLISH</PublishUrl>
    <PublishDir>C:\MyApp\PUBLISH</PublishDir>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <_TargetId>Folder</_TargetId>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

you can also use a relative path like

```
    <PublishUrl>PUBLISH</PublishUrl>
    <PublishDir>PUBLISH</PublishDir>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this on VS build events

```
dotnet publish $(SolutionDir)DIRECTORI_1/PROJECT_1.csproj -c Release -o C:\Deployments\FOLDER_1
```