# How to use "dotnet publish" with a pubxml file?

Tags: .net-core

I have a .net Core application and some `pubxml` files. When I publish from Visual Studio, it works. But I cannot figure out how to publish from the command line.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50332343/dotnet-publish-with-ppublishprofile) does not help:

- `dotnet publish -c Release MyApp /p:PublishProfile=MyApp\Properties\PublishProfiles\Win64.pubxml` publishes a portable version
- Going into the `MyApp` folder does not help either
- The linked question has a [link to a Github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1901) but this is about msbuild, I want to use `dotnet publish`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

There is a newer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58281549/5636299) on that other question that solves your question.

The short version is that you need to supply the path to the project **and** the path to the the pubxml file as arguments for dotnet publish.

```
dotnet publish .\pathToYourProject\projectFile.csproj --configuration Release /p:PublishProfile=.\pathToYourPubXmlFolder\PubProfile.pubxml
```

As noted there, this should work on Windows but doesn't on Linux.