# Dotnet publishing via cmd not possible

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, publish

I'm successfully publishing a .NET Core App via Visual Studio but am unable to do the same via command-line (or using the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019).

I'm using the Publish profile generated by VS2019 and doing:

`dotnet publish -p:PublishProfile=Properties\PublishProfiles\MyProfile.pubxml`

where `MyProfile` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
   <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
   <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
   <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
   <PublishDir>..\Build\Release\publish\</PublishDir>
   <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
   <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
   <PublishSingleFile>False</PublishSingleFile>
   <PublishReadyToRun>False</PublishReadyToRun>
   <PublishTrimmed>False</PublishTrimmed>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

And the error that I always get is:

> MyCustom.dll. Could not load type
> 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.AppDomainIsolatedTask' from assembly
> 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Confirm that the 
> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are
> available, and that the task contains a public class that implements
> Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try `dotnet publish -p:PublishProfile=MyProfile`?

Comment: Yeah, same error

Comment: What if you add `/p:DeployOnBuild=true`? Are you in the correct folder?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. If I add `DeployOnBuild`, the error is the same.
Yeah, I'm in the correct folder, 100% sure

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50332343/dotnet-publish-with-ppublishprofile

Comment: dotnet publish --framework netcoreapp2.2 --configuration Release -o bin\Release\PublishOutput

Comment: Same error. And I already took a look at that stackoverflow question

Comment: I think I finally managed to do it, using:
`msbuild /restore /t:Publish /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win-x64 /p:configuration=Release`

Comment: Post your own answer and accept it to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, rather than a fix.

If we use `msbuild`to publish, I'm able to have the same result as `dotnet publish` and it runs successfully in the command-line:

```
msbuild /restore /t:Publish /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win-x64 /p:configuration=Release
```